# Unexpected token (10:25) in react-leaflet videoOverlay file during webpack build

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

Failed to compile

```
./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/VideoOverlay.js 10:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   var overlay = new LeafletVideoOverlay(url, bounds, options);
|   if (options.play === true) {
>     overlay.getElement()?.play();
|   }
|   return createElementObject(overlay, extendContext(ctx, {
```

Hey,
After I updated my Webpack in React I'm left with this error message from Leaflet. I got through all the step, even completely deleted all my dependancys and reinstalled all Modules I need. Also I updated my Browserlist in package.json . I don't relly know what to do anymore. Can Anyone help me?

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "gsap": "^3.11.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-leaflet-core": "^2.1.1",
    "react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
    "react-page-scroll-progress-bar": "^3.0.1",
    "react-scrollmagic-r18": "^1.0.3",
    "video-react": "^0.16.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.28.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely set up a new Projectand imported all my files and it works again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).